# one big table or normalized two tables insert select performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, normalization

**I have the following create statement:**

```
    CREATE TABLE venues
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  fs_id varchar,
  name varchar,
  phone varchar,
  address varchar,
  latitude double precision,
  longitude double precision,
  city varchar,
  state varchar,
  country varchar,
  category_fs_id varchar,
  category_name varchar,
  CONSTRAINT pk_venue_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I can get what I want with one query, but it is too much columns so I can create one more table like:

```
CREATE TABLE venues
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  fs_id varchar,
  name varchar,
  category_fs_id varchar,
  category_name varchar,
  venue_info_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT pk_venue_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
  CONSTRAINT fk_venue_info_id FOREIGN KEY (venue_info_id)
  REFERENCES venue_info (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);


CREATE TABLE venue_info
(
  phone varchar,
  address varchar,
  latitude double precision,
  longitude double precision,
  city varchar,
  state varchar,
  country varchar,
);
```

but after this I should write two queries for each insert and join tables in select query
Is it decrease performance or I can do it with one query even in this case?

Comment: "too much columns" for what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of that information is specific to the venue you should keep it in one table, rather than having a separate table with extra information. You can have up to about 1600 columns in one table, depending on type. (Although you probably shouldn't!) Try to keep your  tables representative of the entities you're dealing with - a `venue_info` isn't really a specific thing.

Although I could see an argument for having a separate `address` table in your system if you had a number of entities that all had addresses that needed the same details.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion. 
There is no need of breakdown as the table contains all the address details & nothing more. Why do we break down table structure, [goes here](http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/sql-design-why-you-need-database-normalization). 
Hope, this link might help you out.